# Не могу установить Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, pip

Я установил все необходимые пакеты, но когда я устанавливаю Kivy мне выдаётся ~12 ошибок приложения pkg-config.exe (0xc000007b) и Kivy так и не устанавливается. Вот ошибка: [место не хватит на всю ошибку](https://pastebin.com/kHNDZgKk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Официальных сборок Kivy под Python 3.8 еще нет - либо перейди на Python 3.7, либо используй неофициальную сборку (например, [отсюда](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#kivy) - скачай файл `Kivy‑1.11.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl` и установи с помощью `pip install path\to\Kivy‑1.11.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl`).

Если все же позарез необходимо установить Kivy из исходников, нужен установленный [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/). Когда mingw установлен, включить SDL и gstreamer:

```
> set USE_SDL2=1
> set USE_GSTREAMER=1
```

установить зависимости:

```
> pip install --upgrade Cython docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2 kivy_deps.glew kivy_deps.gstreamer kivy_deps.glew_dev kivy_deps.sdl2_dev kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev
```

и собрать Kivy с mingw:

```
> pip install kivy --global-option="build" --global-option="--compiler=mingw" --global-option="build_ext" --global-option="--compiler=mingw"
```